# MyBatis - select data by where enum as ordinal

Tags: enums, mybatis

I have a class with ENUM

```
private OrderStatus status;
```

and sql

```
<select id="getOrder" parameterType="map" resultMap="OrderMap">
SELECT * FROM Order WHERE 
status = #{status, typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler}
</select>
```

and service

```
@Override
public Order getOrder(OrderStatus status) {
    return this.orderMapper.getOrder(status);
}
```

In insert or update SQL that works fine, but in select an error occurs

threw exception [nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Failed invoking constructor for handler class org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object does not represent an enum type.

I can use status.ordinal() to pass parameters to SQL but it's make no sense.

Any hints appreciated

Comment: I have the same problem as you, I debuged and found this: mybatis instance EnumOrdinalTypeHandler with constructor org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler#EnumOrdinalTypeHandler(Class<E> type). and the parameter "type" is java.lang.Object, which is NOT correct. in your case, parameter "type" should be OrderStatus.class And I found a tempory solution: change "where status = ****" to "where status in (****)". it works for me! I think it is a bug of mybatis. I am too busy to report it. (I have to work until 22:00 every day, T_T) Could you please report it to mybatis team?

Answer (score 2):

you should register the EnumOrdinalTypeHandler for your enum class in the mybatis-config.xml

```
<typeHandlers>
        <typeHandler handler="org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler" javaType="com.yourpackage.OrderStatus "/>
</typeHandlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom Enum, then you also should specifiy the javaType attribute of this element. In my case MyBatis had already converted the element to String and thus could not handle it as an enum anymore.

In your example you should try:

```
#{status,
  jdbcType=INTEGER,
  javaType=my.custom.enum.OrderStatus, 
  typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler}
```